# Single antibiotic dose for infection prevention in teeth surgery: Bad idea?

Tags: antibiotics, antibacterial-resistance

I was given a single dose of (I think) amoxicillin before teeth surgery to prevent infection. Appartently this is a common and accepted practice.

Doesn't this promote the development of antibiotic resistant bacteria?

I was taught that patients terminating their antibiotics treatment prematurely is the leading cause for development of resistant strains. And treatments don't get much shorter than single dosage.

But I also vaguely remember reading that current medical opinion is shifting away from this theory. Is this disproved now?

Comment: Except you're not treating an infection with a single shot of antibiotics

Comment: Antibiotic prophylaxis is indicated under a few circumstances, but not that many.